The definition of $Y \cdot Q$ in Hartshorne example II.6.6.2 (intersection of a divisor with a subvariety)
The question comes from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, chapter II, example 6.6.2. Let $Q$ be the nonsingular surface $xy = zw$ in $\Bbb P_{k}^{3}$. Let $Y$ be any irreducible hypersurface of $\Bbb P^3$ which does not contain $Q$. Then Hartshorne defines $Y \cdot Q$ as follows.
Definition On each standard open set $U_i$ of $\Bbb P^3$, $Y$ is defined by a single function $f$; we can take the value of this function (restricted to $Q$) for each valuation of a prime divisor of $Q$ to define the divisor $Y \cdot Q$.
The definition is ambiguous.

On different standard open sets $U_i$ and $U_j$, $Y$ is defined by different functions $f_i$ and $f_j$.
This definition always gives $0$ in $Cl(Q)$. Because $\sum_{Z} v_{Z}(f)Z$ is always a principal divisor.

What is my mistake?

I'll change notation so that the coordinates on $\Bbb P^3$ are $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $Q=V(x_0x_1-x_2x_3)$ (though the coordinates don't really matter - all smooth quadric surfaces in $\Bbb P^3$ are projectively equivalent to each other when working over an algebraically closed field).
This could be stated better. Let $Z$ be a prime divisor on $Q$. I claim that if $U_i\cap Z\neq\emptyset$ and $U_j\cap Z\neq\emptyset$ then the valuations of $f_i|_Q$ and $f_j|_Q$ in $\mathcal{O}_{Q,Z}$ are equal, and we take this common valuation to be the coefficient of $Z$ in $Y\cdot Q$.
Proof the valuations are equal: if $Z$ intersects both $U_i$ and $U_j$, then the generic point of $Z$ lies in $U_i\cap U_j$, which means that $x_i/x_j$ and $x_j/x_i$ are units in $\mathcal{O}_{Q,Z}$. As $f_i = f_j(x_i/x_j)^d$ up to a nonzero constant, the valuations are the same.
To show that this does not always give $0$, let's look at a hyperplane divisor like $Y=V(x_1)$. If $Z$ is a prime divisor which intersects $U_1$, then as the local equation for $Z$ in $U_1$ is $1$, we find by our proof above that the coefficient of $Z$ in $Y\cdot Q$ is zero. Now $V(x_1)\cap Q= V(x_1,x_2x_3)$ consists of the two lines $V(x_1,x_2)$ and $V(x_1,x_3)$, and $x_1/x_i$ has valuation 1 in each such ring for any choice of $i\neq 1$. Thus $Y\cdot Q = [V(x_1,x_2)]+[V(x_1,x_3)]$, which is nonzero.

Generally, $f_i = f_j x_i / x_j$ is not right. But $f_i x_i^{n_i} = f_j x_j^{n_j}$ for some higher powers.

In the answer, $Y \cdot Q$ is just $(x_1)$, a principal divisor, going to zero in $Cl(Q)$.

I find that $(x_1)$ is not in the function field of $Q$, since it is even not of degree $0$.

Agree with the first comment, fixed. It looks like you figured out the issue in the others - $x_1$ isn't a rational function, so its divisor isn't principal.
